# Silverlight OpenFileDialog Filter Property with Extension and file name

Tags: silverlight, filter, filenames, openfiledialog

Is there any way when set the filter property of OpenFileDialog control in Silverlight, we can filter file by extension and part of the file name? For example how do I set the filter property if i just want to show files that starts with letter A and have the extension .dat. Please keep in mind i might have other files with same extension by starts with different letter. I don't want to show those. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Not sure if this would work but in your filter can you do like "Text Files (.txt)|a*.txt but instead of text files your .dat? I can't test this atm because I do not have .net setup on my pc.

Comment: I did try that approach. since in my case i am looking for dat files as opposed to txt file not that it matters, i set up the filter property as 
Convert's ( .DAT )|A*.DAT

But still getting exception of Invalid file filter format

Were you able to make that working or just assuming that it should work? Thanks for the reply again.

Comment: I assumed it might work based on the filter structure. I don't have .NET setup on this PC and don't have the other PC with me. I think you might not be able to do it without finding a custom one or possibly extending it. Never really had to limit the name of the file.

Comment: what is your silverlight version?

Answer (score 0):

Well very old question, but i had similar problem and here is how it worked for me:

```
 private void BrowseExcelFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //This needs to be before try statement othervise exception is thrown ("Dialogs must be user-initiated")
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        try
        {

            openFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls,*.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
               ...
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```